# Another example of virtual calls vs. type-checking

Tags: c#, polymorphism, factory-pattern

### Problem

I swear, every time I get it pounded into my brain that I should be using virtual calls vs. type-checking (eg:

```
if (obj is Foo)
   ...
else if (obj is Bar)
   ...
```

... I come up with another example where I don't know how to implement the former.

I'm implementing a packetized protocol over a serial port. Some pseudo-code will explain this best:

```
OnDataReceived:
    RcvPacket p = RcvPacket.ReadPacket(comport);   // Call factory method
    if (p is RcvPacketFoo)
        OnFoo();
    if (p is RcvPacketBar)
        OnBar();

OnFoo:
    raise Foo event
OnBar:
    raise Bar event
```

Basically, ReadPacket is a **factory method** in the *base class* that determines the type of packet being received, and passes the buffer to the correct derived-type constructor. After this, I need to raise an event, depending on the type of packet. How can I do this without using the `is` operator? Is my method sound/sane?

---

### Solution

The [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), of course! Thanks [Pablo Romeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373170/pablo-romeo).

In this case, I made the controller, that is calling the factory method, is the visitor. My result:

```
public interface IPacketHandler {
    void Handle(FooPacket p);
    void Handle(BarPacket p);
}

public class Controller : IPacketHandler {
    OnDataReceived() {
        RcvPacket p = RcvPacket.ReadPacket(comport);   // Call factory method
        p.Handle(this);        // *** Virtual Call: The first dispatch ***
    }

    // Note the use of explicit interface implementation here.
    IPacketHandler.Handle(FooPacket p) {
       OnFoo();
    }
    IPacketHandler.Handle(BarPacket p) {
       OnBar();
    }
}

public abstract class RcvPacket {
    public static RcvPacket ReadPacket(...) { ... }   // Factory method
    public void Handle(IPacketHandler handler);
}
public class FooPacket : RcvPacket {
    public override void Handle(IPacketHandler handler) {
       handler.Handle(this);        // *** Overloaded call: The second dispatch ***
    }
}
public class BarPacket : RcvPacket {
    public override void Handle(IPacketHandler handler) {
       handler.Handle(this);        // *** Overloaded call: The second dispatch ***
    }
}
```

The fun thing here, is that by explicitly implementing the visitor interface, the `Handle` calls are essentially hidden.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461.aspx):

> A class that implements an interface can explicitly implement a member of that interface. When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface.

Comment: The class that receives the packet should not be the class that processes it.  Once you separate these concerns, it should be obvious how ProcessPacket can be the base class of classes that process packets, instead of RcvPacket.  With a virtual OnProcess() method.

Comment: @HansPassant I think I follow you... care to provide a small code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, considering that you probably don't want much additional logic inside each packet, you can accomplish it through [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

In that case, I'd probably create an interface, such as:

```
public interface IPacketEvents 
{
    void On(Foo foo);
    void On(Bar bar);
}
```

I'm assuming you have a base class for all packets. In it I would declare:

```
public abstract void RaiseUsing(IPacketEvents events);
```

And each subclass of package would implement the following:

```
public override void RaiseUsing(IPacketEvents events) 
{
    events.On(this);
}
```

You could either have a new class implement the `IPacketEvents` or that same class from where you call the factory could implement it.
In that second case, your call would end up as:

```
OnDataReceived:
    RcvPacket p = RcvPacket.ReadPacket(comport);   // Call factory method
    p.RaiseUsing(this);
```

Using this type of dispatch, what you get, is that each type, calls the corresponding method, because it "knows" which one to call.
It may confuse a bit that I used the same "On" name for all methods, but that's not entirely necessary. They could be OnFoo() and OnBar().

This type of behavior is also used in the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: And there it is: My first real use of the Visitor Pattern. I've been wondering for a while where I would use this! The cherry on top is explicitly implementing `IPacketEvents` (in my class that calls the factory), so that you don't have these strange `On(...)` public methods hanging out there.

Comment: :) Now, one thing to take into account: You don't necessarily need to have them public. You could declare the interface as `internal`, as well as the `RaiseUsing` methods. That way, it will only be accessible from your own assembly.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of is to move the implementation of `OnFoo` and `OnBar` to the `RcvPacketFoo` and `RcvPacketBar` classes.

```
public class RcvPacket{
     public abstract void On(RcvPacketHandler eh);
}
public class RcvPacketFoo : RcvPacket
{
     public override void On(RcvPacketHandler eh){eh.OnFoo();} //OnFoo implemenation
}

public class RcvPacketBar : RcvPacket
{
     public override void On(RcvPacketHandler eh){eh.OnBar();} //OnBar implemenation
}
//Update following your comment:
public class RcvPacketHandler
{
public void OnFoo(){}
public void OnBar(){}
//....
OnDataReceived:
    RcvPacket p = RcvPacket.ReadPacket(comport);   // Call factory method
    p.On(this);
```

Comment: If I knew what the implementation of On... was, that may work. Except here, the result of `OnFoo()` and `OnBar()` are to raise `Foo` and `Bar` events for client code to handle.

Comment: Aside from `OnFoo` and `OnBar` having to be public, yes. Now I think I'm just getting picky. Also, `EventHandler` should probably have a different, non-conflicting name. :-P

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot think of a way to preserve the access modifiers. Seems that the different behaviours have to go into the different implementations. I did rename the `EventHandler` though :).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gave it to Pablo, though - because he specifically points out that this is the visitor pattern / double dispatch. And the use of the `interface` allows for explicit interface implementation, which hides the `On...` methods in the handler class.

Comment: Yeah, I think we are both basically saying the same thing using different words. Thanks ;)