# "Tag" strings inside List<>

Tags: c#, string, list

I have three types of strings which I need to put into single a List in a particular order. By 'three types' I mean that there are three ways of treating a string.
I thought of using a `struct` like this to put in the list:

```
struct Chunk
{
    public char Type;   // 'A', 'B' or 'C'.
    public string Text;
}
```

Maybe there's a better way of marking a string with how it should be processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use a `struct` here - a class should do just fine. There are pre-built data types that you could use for tagging:

- `KeyValuePair<K,V>`, the type used in dictionary iterators, lets you pair a value with a key without defining a new type
- Starting with .NET 4.0 you can use `Tuple<T1,T2>` for pairing items of arbitrary types.

I would suggest defining an `enum` instead of using `char` for the type: this should give your program better readability.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This will give you Intellisense and error checking.

```
struct Chunk
{
    public TheType Type;   // 'A', 'B' or 'C'.
    public string Text;
}

enum TheType { A, B, C }
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you are going to use these chunks, polymorphism might be your friend. The `Type` of the chunk actually carries your "`Type`" information:

```
public abstract class Chunk {
   public string Text { get; private set; }

   protected Chunk(string text) {
      Text = text;
   }
}

public class ATypeChunk : Chunk {
   public ATypeChunk(string text) : base(text) { }
}

public class BTypeChunk : Chunk {
   public BTypeChunk(string text) : base(text) { }
}
```

Creating the chunks from some source:

```
public IEnumerable<Chunk> GetChunks(string dataToBeParsed) {
   while ( /* data to be parsed */ ) {

      // Determine chunk type

      switch ( /* some indicator of chunk type */ ) {
         case 'A':
            yield return new ATypeChunk(chunkText);
         case 'B':
            yield return new BTypeChunk(chunkText);
      }     
   }
}
```

Then, here's what you *don't* do when using them*:

```
public UseChunk(Chunk chunk) {
   if (chunk is ATypeChunk)
      // Do something A specific
   else if (chunk is BTypeChunk)
      // Do something B specific
}
```

* Okay, you *can*, but there are probably better ways.  For example the [Visitor Pattern](http://dorkasaurusrex.blogspot.com/2009/10/implementing-visitor-pattern-pattern-in.html) has a common usage here.

Here is a question I asked when I was still trying to wrap my head around all of this:

- [Another example of virtual calls vs. type-checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746417/another-example-of-virtual-calls-vs-type-checking)

Answer (score -2):

Take an eye on the Array.Sort method :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx

Comment: FWIW I didn't downvote, but that doesn't answer the question.